# SharePoint update existing List Workflow 2013 and overwrite old version

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I need to update the existing sharepoint workflow, but when i publish the workflow that old version workflow is still running. Could i know anyway to replace old version and run a new workflow?

is it only the way, when i stop all workflow in list by powershell before i publish the new workflow 2013?
Any ideas, thank you.

*note : my workflow is build by SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 0):

That is default behavior. If you have already running wf it will run under old definition. WF have versions. So if you want the new WF to apply you need to stop running ones, publish and start the wf again. PowerShell is probably best option to do that (stop and start)